# How to Convert nAn to 0

Tags: javascript

Array with json
how to convert isNaN to number zero
so if you ahve array 1,2,3 and subtract 1,2 how to subtract
1-1
2-2
3- NaN
NaN should be 0 for 3-0

```
// Create variables to append player's + or - score per hole
        var golfStroke = scores[y].strokes[q];
        var parStroke = pars[z];
        var scoreStroke = parStroke - golfStroke;
        // Create if statement to change undefined array values to number 0 for calculation
        var isNum = function () {
            if (isNaN(golfStroke)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return golfStroke;
        }
        if (isNaN(parStroke)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return parStroke;
        };
        }
        console.log("The over or minus par is: " + scoreStroke);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A simple shorthand way of using `0` if you have `NaN` is to use [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
var x = somethingThatMayBeNaN || 0;
```

Since `NaN` is falsey, if `somethingThatMayBeNaN` is `NaN` (or `0` or any other falsey value), `x` will be set to `0`. If `somethingThatMayBeNaN` is truthy, `x` will be set to `somethingThatMayBeNaN`. When you're dealing with a numeric calculation, usually the only falsey values that you may have are `0` or `NaN`.

---

"Falsey" and "truthy": The "falsey" values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course, `false`. Everything is is "truthy".

Comment: it's a good trick to use, but always think of you reading your code in 6 months, and add a comment before such a line to say explicitly what you're doing

Comment: @zmo: For very common idioms like this one, I wouldn't think you needed to call it out specifically. (This is probably in the top 10 JavaScript idioms.) I **am** a great believer in thinking about the poor sod (possibly yourself!) who has to maintain your code in six months, though. :-) If you think that person will be unfamiliar with it, a comment is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

This will check if the value is NaN and then it assigns 0 to it.

```
anyNan = isNaN(anyNan) ? 0 : anyNan;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming is `golfStroke` that could be `NaN`, for example:

```
var scoreStroke = parStroke - ~~golfStroke;
```

In that way any number would remains the same, and any "falsy" value – like `NaN` – would become `0`.